# Spark: value mean is not a member of Array[Any]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using an RDD from a dataframe to calculate an average for a column.  Here is my RDD

```
 dataframe.rdd.map(x => (x(2))).take(5)
 # res51: Array[Any] = Array(499, 200, 400, 151, 65)
```

I'm looking for the mean of that Array.  Here is my code:

```
 dataframe.rdd.map(x => (x(2))).mean

 <console>:31: error: value mean is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any]
          dataframe.rdd.map(x => (x(2))).mean
```

Comment: You forgot to typecast the x(3) variable to double. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `dataframe` as below

```
+----+----+------+
|col1|col2|col3  |
+----+----+------+
|a   |1   |908.76|
|b   |2   |901.74|
|c   |3   |83.71 |
|d   |5   |39.36 |
|e   |2   |234.64|
+----+----+------+
```

You can calculate *mean* in `dataframe` by using `mean` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(mean("col3").as("mean").show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-------+
|mean   |
+-------+
|433.642|
+-------+
```

If you insist on using `RDD` then you can do the following

```
df.rdd.map(x => (x(2).asInstanceOf[Double])).mean
```

here I have used `2` because thats the column I would want the `mean`. **The only mistake you did was that you forgot to typecast the `x(3)` variable which was default to `Any` and *scala compiler* couldn't find method mean for `Any` dataType**.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: hmm Interesting. Didn't know the methods changes with the Type. Great answer. or you can use `getDouble` `df.rdd.map(x => x.getDouble(2))`

Comment: @Psidom This is typical for scala (implicit conversion). The method `mean` is in the class `DoubleRDDFunctions` and only available to `RDD[Double]` by an implicit  conversion